# AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'member'

Tags: python, discord

У меня есть готовое логирование дискорд сервера, но у меня возникла проблема с выводом сообщений в один канал. Когда я пытаюсь произвести логирование на канал мне пишет: AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'member'.

вот сам код

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel(915546470780911617)#id
    await message.channel.send(message.content, message.member)
```

Comment: ну значит нет у message аттрибута member. В чем заключается вопрос?

Comment: выведите message и посмотрите что туда передается, и от данных которые хранит переменная mesasge уже отталкивайтесь, если не знаете как - отправьте сюда все что передается в message